# Template specialisation of a static function is shown in Doxygen-genered documentation

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen, template-specialization

In a C++ header of my project, I am using few static template functions helpers which are called in the non-static public functions.

When I run Doxygen on this file, each static function is hidden even when using templates, which is the correct behavior since static functions will not be visible for the outter-world. But when I do a template specialization on one of these, this specialization will appear in generated documentation :

```
// This will not appear in documentation, ok
template<class T>
static T my_function(...)

// However this will appear ! :(
template<>
SomeClass my_function(...)
```

If think this is because Doxygen is not smart enough to see that this specialization is for a static function and so this specialization appears like a regular one. But maybe I am wrong.

What can I do in order to hide this from my documentation?

Answer (score 2):

It is always possible to hide sections of code from Doxygen using `@cond` and `@endcond` around the code.

It's the doxygen equivalent of `#if 0` / `#endif`