# Hide Template Specialization Parameters in Doxygen Output

Tags: c++, doxygen, template-specialization

I'm writing a library which makes extensive use of meta-programing, and has traits classes such as

```
/// Doxygen comments...
template<class T>
struct unit_traits<T, typename void_t<
    typename T::base_unit_type,
    typename T::conversion_ratio,
    typename T::pi_exponent_ratio,
    typename T::translation_ratio>::type>
{
    typedef typename T::base_unit_type base_unit_type;          ///< typedef documentation
    typedef typename T::conversion_ratio conversion_ratio;      ///< typedef documentation
    typedef typename T::pi_exponent_ratio pi_exponent_ratio;    ///< typedef documentation
    typedef typename T::translation_ratio translation_ratio;    ///< typedef documentation
};
```

However, the specialization is just an implementation detail (there are other places where specializations are used to end recursions, etc), and it clutters the doxygen output, since the library user only really needs to know that `unit_traits<someType>::...` is available. Is there some way to hide the specializations parameters in the documentation, preferably without creating dummy documentation targets?

**UPDATE**

Just to be clear, I've attempted the following, and they do not hide the specialization:

```
    template<class T>
    struct unit_traits
/** @cond */
        <T, typename void_t<
        typename T::base_unit_type,
        typename T::conversion_ratio,
        typename T::pi_exponent_ratio,
        typename T::translation_ratio>::type>
/** @endcond */
    {
        typedef typename T::base_unit_type base_unit_type;
        typedef typename T::conversion_ratio conversion_ratio;
        typedef typename T::pi_exponent_ratio pi_exponent_ratio;
        typedef typename T::translation_ratio translation_ratio;
    };
```

and

```
template<class T>
        struct unit_traits
    #ifndef DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
            <T, typename void_t<
            typename T::base_unit_type,
            typename T::conversion_ratio,
            typename T::pi_exponent_ratio,
            typename T::translation_ratio>::type>
    #endif
        {
            typedef typename T::base_unit_type base_unit_type;              
            typedef typename T::conversion_ratio conversion_ratio;                                      
            typedef typename T::pi_exponent_ratio pi_exponent_ratio;                                
            typedef typename T::translation_ratio translation_ratio;                                    
        };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979469/template-specialisation-of-a-static-function-is-shown-in-doxygen-genered-documen

Comment: it's not a duplicate of that question, because you can't /** @cond */ just the specialization, you have to ignore the entire struct using that method. I still want `struct unit_traits` to be documented, I just don't want it to show the specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doxygen FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html), you can use the preprocessor to basically have doxygen see a different version of your code (whether this is a good idea or not is a separate question).

So, presumably you could do something like this:

```
/** Doxygen doc for general-form unit_traits. */
template<typename General>
class unit_traits;
```

Now, you can fool doxygen (again, caveat at the end) like this:

```
#ifndef DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
// Code actually being built.
template<>
class unit_traits<int>
#else // DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
/** Doxygen comment for the int case. */
class unit_traits
#endif // DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
{
....
};
```

Your compiler will be fine with this. Regarding doxygen, it will either work or not - since it's not really valid C++ code to have `unit_traits` both template and not, doxygen will either buy it or not, and even if it does, next version might not.

Clearly, you could do something like this, though:

```
#ifndef DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
// Code actually being built.
template<>
class unit_traits<int>
#else // DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
/** Doxygen comment for the int case. */
class int_unit_traits
#endif // DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
{
...
};
```

Since both preprocessor paths are valid C++ (well, sort of), your compiler *and* doxygen should be happy.

---

**Caveat**

Personally, I think that the fact that you're trying to "fool" doxygen indicates that there's a conceptual problem. Heavily-templated C++ is borderline undocumentable, and doxygen does a better job at it than I could do in a million years, but it's still problematic.

In similar cases, I usually just place all documentation, for the general case and the specializations - in a doxygen comment for the general case. I make doxygen ignore the specializations (using the preprocessor), and just put a non-doxygen comment on each saying that the documentation is in the general case. Admittedly, this is crappy too :-)

Comment: I don't want to skip the entire definition, I just want the part between the <..> not to show up.

Comment: It's the preprocessor. You are not constrained to put it around complete definitions. If you use it to surround *anything*, the compiler won't mind.

Comment: check out the update to the question. It either doesn't work in the case or I'm using it wrong.

Comment: I understand your question less and less, I must say - in particular the relationship to your comment above. At some point, you must have a general definition of the class. You can document that if you want. If there's any specialization you don't want DoxyGen to see, just wrap it up completely in the preprocessor directive. Not sure why an "end case of a template recursion"  would have to do with " the part between the <..> not to show up".

Comment: the unspecialized version of the traits class would be `template<typename> unit_traits;`. It wouldn't include any of the member typedefs, and so documenting that and ignoring the specialization won't help. What I'd like to do, which maybe the answer is 'you can't', is document the specialized version of the class but have it show up in the docs as `unit_traits` instead of `unit_traits<lots characters used for the specialization that the user doesn't care about>`

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus OK, I think I understand it now. See update.

Comment: @AmiTavory -- There are lots of people at this site who would dispute your claim that "heavily-templated C++ is borderline undocumentable" (or my claim that heavily templated C++ is borderline unmaintainable). I can grok those templates (usually). Most people, however, when they look at my templates do something like this: (☉_☉)

Comment: @DavidHammen That's the spitting image of me looking at boost source code :-)

Comment: @AmiTavory -- Try looking at eigen. Underneath the hood, it's templates from here to there. Ignore all the template magic and it just works. It's magic!

Comment: @DavidHammen I'm sure you're right. Working my way through [linux.fm](http://www.linux.fm/) first, though :-)